# php 7 как отключить warning при не-передаче в функцию какого-то параметра?

Tags: php

При этом не отключая остальные варнинги. Мне просто не нужен конкретно этот тип варнингов

```
 function aaaaa($a,$b) {

 return false; }


 aaaaa("1");

 <b>Warning</b>:  Missing argument 2 for aaaaa(), called in [...][...]
 on line 9 and defined in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

Comment: для этого используются значения по умолчанию `function aaaaa($a=null,$b=null){}`

Answer (score 0):

Сделать второй параметр опциональным (по умолчанию).

> Значения аргументов по умолчанию
>
> Функция может определять значения по умолчанию в стиле C++ для
>   скалярных аргументов, например:
>
> Пример #3 Использование значений по умолчанию в определении функции

```
<?php
function makecoffee($type = "капучино")
{
return "Готовим чашку $type.\n";
}
echo makecoffee(); //Вывод: Готовим чашку капучино.
echo makecoffee(null); //Вывод: Готовим чашку .
echo makecoffee("эспрессо");//Вывод: Готовим чашку эспрессо.
```

[Пример взят с php.net (+ пояснение)](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php)

Или если вы именно хотите убрать данный Warning (как он есть), то можно написать свой обработчик ошибок `set_error_handler`

[Описание](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php)